# zsh: command not found: grm

Tags: catalina

I recently updated to Catalina and some commands are not being found. For example I have alias in my .zprofile for rm, mkdir, mv. mkdir works fine but rm it doesn't. Does anyone know why some commands are working and some not?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you post your `.zprofile` file to better troubleshoot your issue?

Comment: Also, where is`grm` installed and is its path part of PATH?